# How to put user defined dynamic mapping while putting the data in elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-kinesis-firehose, elasticsearch-mapping

I have a document which I want to send in a newly created index (mapping is not yet done). Below is sample document ,

```
{
   "client" : "",
   "timestamp" : 1587995978942,
   "log_level" : "INFO",
   "log_message" : "Some big message"
}
```

Now I want to create mapping *without calling mapping api*. *Elasticsearch will add default mapping* based on my data like *client* and *log_level* will be of type **text**.But in any possible way am I able to add this mapping by my own without calling mapping api because I want to make *client* and *log_level* fields of type **keyword**. I am using *AWS kinesis firehose delivery* stream to put data into elasticsearch which dont allow me to create mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One typically uses [dynamic_templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) but those are also defined within the `mappings` settings of your index...

An alternative could be utilizing the [index template APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html).